# Xamarin iOS UITableView.Source NullReferenceException

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios

I've created a **UITableViewCell** but when setting the source of the **UITableView**, I get a **NullReferenceException**.

```
public partial class SessionOverviewViewController : UIViewController
{

    public List<BaseSessionController> Sessions;

    public SessionOverviewViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        tvTable.RegisterClassForCellReuse(typeof(SessionTableViewCell), "SessionCell");
        SessionTableViewSource source = new SessionTableViewSource(Sessions);
        tvTable.Source = source; //This line throws the Exception
    }
}
```

The TableViewSource:

```
    public class SessionTableViewSource : UITableViewSource
{
    List<BaseSessionController> TableItems;
    string CellIdentifier = "SessionCell";

    public SessionTableViewSource(List<BaseSessionController> items)
    {
        TableItems = items;
    }

    public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, nint section)
    {
        return TableItems.Count;
    }

    public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        SessionTableViewCell cell = (SessionTableViewCell)tableView.DequeueReusableCell(CellIdentifier);
        BaseSessionController friend = TableItems[indexPath.Row];

        //---- if there are no cells to reuse, create a new one
        if (cell == null)
        {
            //cell = new SessionTableViewCell(new NSString(CellIdentifier), friend.FriendName, new UIImage(NSData.FromArray(friend.FriendPhoto)));
            cell = new SessionTableViewCell(new NSString(CellIdentifier), friend);
        }

        //cell.UpdateCellData(friend.UserName, new UIImage(NSData.FromArray(friend.FriendPhoto)));

        return cell;
    }
}
```

And the Cell itself

```
public partial class SessionTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
{
    public BaseSessionController Session;

    public SessionTableViewCell (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
    }

    public SessionTableViewCell(NSString cellId, BaseSessionController session) : base(UITableViewCellStyle.Default, cellId)
    {
        Session = session;
        lblDate.Text = Session.Model.SessionStartTime.ToString("d");
    }
}
```

Hopefully someone can see the mistake I made and can help me with this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you debug and check if GetCell or RowsInSection are getting executed? or  "source " is not null?

Comment: btw, Do you have cell with identifier "SessionCell" in storyboard or xib ? I think thats problem

Comment: Both methods don't get executed, and I check `source`. It is definitely not null, also the `UITableView` outlet is not null, etc. And yes, I set the identifier inside the Storyboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reviewing the Storyboard, it was discovered that tvTable was actually a Scroll View.
Frustratingly useless error message :)

Comment: Extremely useless, but thank you a lot for helping me!!

Answer (score 0):

you should register cell to UITableView

```
tvTable.RegisterClassForCellReuse(typeof(SessionTableViewCell), "SessionCell");
```

change your code

```
public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    SessionTableViewCell cell = (SessionTableViewCell)tableView.DequeueReusableCell(CellIdentifier);
    BaseSessionController friend = TableItems[indexPath.Row];


    cell.Session = friend;

    return cell;
}
```

and

```
public partial class SessionTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
{
    private BaseSessionController  _session;
    public BaseSessionController Session
    {
        get { return _session; }
        set
        {
            _session = value;
            if(value != null)
            {
                lblDate.Text = value.Model.SessionStartTime.ToString("d");
            }
        }
    }

    public SessionTableViewCell (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
    } 
}
```

Comment: The line `cell = new SessionTableViewCell();` will make some problems because I need to provide a `IntPtr` Variable

Comment: sorry, you should remove `if(cell = null)`  see my answer update

Comment: Okay, but I still get the same error at the same line

Comment: If you registered cell type , `tableView.DequeueReusableCell` will auto generate a cell.

Comment: What do you mean? I pasted the Line `tvTable.RegisterClassForCellReuse(typeof(SessionTableViewCell), "SessionCell");` right in front of `SessionTableViewSource source = new SessionTableViewSource(Sessions);
   tvTable.Source = source;` but this does not solve the Exception

Comment: I according to the article tried again, no problem. Can you post code of ViewDidLoad

Comment: I edited the code above, but there is no code inside `ViewDidLoad`

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

In `ViewDidLoad`:

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
{    
    base.ViewDidLoad();
    SessionTableViewSource source = new SessionTableViewSource(Sessions);
    tvTable.Source = source;
}
```

In your `TableViewSource` -> `GetCell` put this:

```
public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    BaseSessionController friend = TableItems[indexPath.Row];
    var cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell ("SessionCell") as SessionTableViewCell;
    cell.Update(friend);
    return cell;
}
```

And in your `SessionTableViewCell` put this:

```
public void UpdateCell(BaseSessionController friend)
{
    Session = session;
    lblDate.Text = Session.Model.SessionStartTime.ToString("d");
}
```

Comment: It still crashes with a NullReferenceException :/

Comment: @Daniel Try changing `GetCell` to just return `new UITableViewCell();` and see what happens

Comment: This just throws the same Exception, because GetCell is not called before `tvTable.Source = source;`

Comment: That's so strange. I just created a quick test projects. Works with no issues at all?! I would try to do a new project to eliminate any weird issues persisting

Comment: Well, creating a new project seems the real last step that should be done. There must be any other solution, and I bet it was me doing something wrong :S

Comment: You could try putting your project on Github or similar. It may be some strange thing in the Storyboard

Comment: And the big problem here is that this is a research project and I am not allowed to share the project to people outside my company, sorry :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134762/discussion-between-angak-and-daniel-dirtynative-martin).